# C# Linq query.Date Between Dates don't work

Tags: c#, linq, date, filter

I tried on two ways to choose to date only from the date frame but still, I get the wrong result. I saw another post but the response doesn't work for me. Please help mine.

```
 List<Measurement> measurementsForTemplate = await databaseCommandContext.CreateSet<Measurement>()
                .Include(v => v.MeasuredValues)
                .Where(x => x.MeasurementFormTemplateId == command.TemplateId )
                .Where(v => v.MeasuredValues.Any(d => d.Time >= command.FromDate))
                .Where(v => v.MeasuredValues.Any(d => d.Time <= command.ToDate)).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Or I created an object without filtering in the above query and then

```
    var measurementsForTemplateDateLimit = measurementsForTemplate.Where(b => b.MeasuredValues
    .Any(d => d.Time >= command.FromDate && d.Time <= command.ToDate)).Select(b => b);
```

Comment: Please, share the example data and expected result. This expression `d.Time >= command.FromDate` tells that you compare the time and date (according to properties names)

Comment: This usually happens because of incorrect types... for example the database value might be stored as a string... or the POCO properties are strings, etc.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski All values have DatTime type.                                                          d.Time= 20.02.2020 , d.Time= 24.02.2020, d.Time= 26.02.2020                                          FromDate=19.02.2020,ToDate=25.02.2020                                                                                    Result- On MeasuredValues should be only object with date 20.02.2020 ,24.02.2020.

Comment: @rfmodulator all values have DaTime type.I tried also on this way I tryied also on this way                                                                                                                                                             `var measurementsForTemplateDateLimit = measurementsForTemplate.Where(b     => b.MeasuredValues.Any(d => d.Time >= command.FromDate && d.Time <=    command.ToDate)).Select(b => b);`

Comment: There are 6 ranges when comparing two date ranges 1) A ends before B starts 2) A starts before B, and A ends before B Ends 3) A starts before B starts and A ends after B ends 4) A starts after B starts and A ends before B ends 5) A starts after B starts and A ends after B ends 6) A starts after B ends.

Comment: @jdweng Ok i Will check that.But for example return  should just two values becouse     `(26.02.2020 >=  19.02.2020 &&  26.02.2020  <=  19.02.2020)=false`

Comment: @jdweng for example thats works `if(date1>=from && date1<= to) //true
            {
                test.Add(date1);
            }

            if (date2>= from && date2<= to)//true
            {
                test.Add(date2);
            }

            if (date3>= from && date3<= to)  //false
            {
                test.Add(date3);
            }`

Comment: What is the right answer 1) The start date falls between the two date 2) The end date falls between the two dates 3) Both the start and end dates fall between the two dates?

Comment: @jdweng  option 3. I want all values from selected from
time range and results should include start and end dates date. The above example, on normal if the condition works correctly. When iI use  LINQ  then return  date3 but this is outside the  time range .Example should return d1,d2.                                  `d1=16/03/2020 d2=20/03/2020, d3=25.05.2020, fromDate=16/03/2020, toDate=22/03/2020`

Comment: @jdweng  like in SQL`from prod in dal.Products Where DateAdded Between startDate and endDate`

Comment: I know where I make mistake.I choose correct objects from the second list but i don't remove the object which is outside the time range.How I can do this ?

Comment: Are there *two* date ranges at play here?  The code shown only looks like there's one, but then the comments are getting into having two.

Answer (score 0):

See figure below with solution
[image]