# SQL query to return records from day/time to another day/time

Tags: c#, datetime, date-range

I have a sql datatable ("Service") with starttime (datetime) and endtime (datetime).
I need to return all records where any part of a Service time range falls within or overlaps a parameter of a start day of week and time and an end day of week and time.  For example, find all records that either start in, end in or overlap the time range of Friday at 5pm to Monday 8am.
Thanks

Comment: See my answer at following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852814/c-sharp-linq-query-date-between-dates-dont-work/60865198#60865198

Comment: You are looking to use the C# objects or the SQL query to filter your results ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, including code.  See [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).